# Format date / time with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following date format: `1/6/2014 7:28`.

I want to plot this along with other dates in the same format along the x-axis of a d3.js graph.

I am using `var format = d3.time.format('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M').parse;` but the console just returns `null`,

After the call to the data I am doing

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.timestamp = format(d.timestamp);
});
```

Am I doing this the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string you specified does not match the format of the date you are trying to parse. In particular the separators are different.

Try this:

```
var format = d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').parse;
```

Instead of:

```
var format = d3.time.format('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M').parse;
```

Comment: Sorry to ask another, but once doing this the x axis plots the same value all the way along it.

Comment: So instead of each date in the data it is plotting the same time without a date (11pm). 11pm will mean nothing to you, but let's just say the value is the same all the way along the x axis instead of each value

Comment: @Alan this probably has to do with how big the range of your data is. Post a new question with the data for your axis, a screenshot of what it looks like and a description of how you want it to look like for more help.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652925/d3-time-format-x-axis-showing-same-value

Comment: Please see:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652925/d3-time-format-x-axis-showing-same-value