# d3 time format x axis showing same value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot dates along the x axis of a d3.js graph. However I am getting the same value repeated along the a axis, when there should be different values instead.

I am formatting the date as follows:

`var format = d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').parse;`

Then directly after the data call:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.timestamp = format(d.timestamp); // d.timestamp is from the data
});
```

Then setting the domain as follows:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue), d3.max(data, xValue)]);

timestamp   location    price   FirstName   LastName
1/6/2014 7:28   Brew've Been Served 11.34   Edvard  Vann
1/6/2014 7:34   Hallowed Grounds    52.22   Hideki  Cocinaro
1/6/2014 7:35   Brew've Been Served 8.33    Stenig  Fusil
1/6/2014 7:36   Hallowed Grounds    16.72   Birgitta    Frente
1/6/2014 7:37   Brew've Been Served 4.24    Sven    Flecha
1/6/2014 7:38   Brew've Been Served 4.17    Cornelia    Lais
1/6/2014 7:42   Coffee Cameleon 28.73   Linnea  Bergen
1/6/2014 7:43   Brew've Been Served 9.6 Mat Bramar
1/6/2014 7:43   Brew've Been Served 16.9    Brand   Tempestad
1/6/2014 7:47   Hallowed Grounds    16.53   Emile   Arpa
1/6/2014 7:48   Hallowed Grounds    10.66   Kare    Orilla
1/6/2014 7:49   Coffee Cameleon 8.39    Bertrand    Ovan
1/6/2014 7:52   Brew've Been Served 32.83   Hennie  Osvaldo
1/6/2014 7:54   Hallowed Grounds    16.88   Nils    Calixto
1/6/2014 7:54   Coffee Cameleon 11.86   Adra    Nubarron
1/6/2014 7:54   Hallowed Grounds    32.93   Rachel  Pantanal
1/6/2014 7:55   Hallowed Grounds    8.05    Lucas   Alcazar
1/6/2014 7:55   Brew've Been Served 3.67    Varja   Lagos
1/6/2014 7:59   Brew've Been Served 8.88    Inga    Ferro
1/6/2014 8:00   Brew've Been Served 4.27    Ruscella    Mies Haber
1/6/2014 8:00   Hallowed Grounds    9.69    Anda    Ribera
1/6/2014 8:01   Hallowed Grounds    10.07   Lidelse Dedos
1/6/2014 8:06   Brew've Been Served 18.24   Loreto  Bodrogi
```

[image]

As you can see in the image below the same value is being plotted along the x axis.

Am I doing this the correct way?

Comment: Could you post complete code and an example of your data please?

Comment: My guess is that your data isn't parsed correctly and `d.timestamp` contains only the date part, not the time.

Comment: d.timestamp does contain the time as well as the date: console.log(d.timestamp[0]) returns Date 2014-01-17T12:00:00.000Z

Comment: `d.timestamp[0]`? So `d.timestamp` is an array?

Comment: That was to log the first [0] d.timestamp

Comment: That's not what `console.log(d.timestamp[0])` does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63936/discussion-between-alan-and-lars-kotthoff).

Comment: @Alan, could you please post (and accept) an answer saying that upgrading D3 to the latest version solved your problem? It might help others who come this question. Thanks!

Comment: @musically_ut I have answered the question saying Lars helped. There was no direct answer posted to this question so I couldn't accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Lars Kotthoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff)
who pointed out I was using an ancient version of d3. Simply changing to a newer version of d3 solved my issue. He answered this via a chat so there was no direct answer to mark up as the correct one. But he solved the issue.